# Cannot import visa after installing pyvisa on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, visa

I installed python with homebrew and installed pyvisa with pip, now when I run `import visa`, I got the following error:

```
OSError: dlopen(/usr/local/vxipnp/linux/bin/libvisa.so.7, 6): image not found
```

It seems like it's looking for NI-VISA at wrong location, how can I fix this?

On the pyvisa website [FAQ](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#error-image-not-found) it says

> Error: Image not found
>
> This error occurs when you have provided an invalid path for the VISA library. Check that the path provided to the constructor or in the configuration file

But how do I check the path?

Answer (score 0):

The file that needs modification is vpp43.py.
However, the packages of PyVISA installed from 'pip' or 'easy_install' on Mac OS will be installed under .egg file:

```
$ /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PyVISA-1.5.dev4-py2.7.egg
```

I could not find a way to modify this, therefore I recompiled the original code by downloading it in a given director

```
$ mkdir pyvisacode
$ cd pyvisacode
$ curl -OL https://github.com/hgrecco/pyvisa/tarball/master
```

When it is downloaded extract it by

```
$ tar -zxvf master
```

A file will be created in the same directory. Navigate to

```
$ cd hgrecco-pyvisa-4cbdbc9/pyvisa/legacy
```

and run Xcode or any other text editor

```
$ open -a Xcode vpp43.py
```

In the opened vpp43.py find

```
path = "/usr/local/vxipnp/linux/bin/libvisa.so.7"
```

Comment this line and replace it with

```
#path = "/usr/local/vxipnp/linux/bin/libvisa.so.7"
path = "/Library/Frameworks/visa.framework/visa"
```

Now you can install PyVISA by

```
 $ cd ../../
 $ sudo python setup.py install
```

Don't forget to run your python in 32 bit. More details can be found here http://bardagjy.com/?p=1245.

I hope this will be fixed in the next PyVISA update!

Good luck